# Mouting a remote drive with cifs

Tags: debian, permissions, mount, fstab, cifs

I've created a remote mounted drive by adding this to my `/etc/fstab`:

```
\\192.x.x.x\web /mnt/web cifs username=X,password=X,domain=X
```

and mounting it with `sudo mount /mnt/web` (which works perfectly!)

The problem is that I can only mount the drive as root. Running `mount /mnt/web` (without sudo) results in the error

> mount: only root can mount \192.x.x.x\web on /mnt/web

I read [this guide](https://www.strika.co/ubuntu-14-04-how-to-properly-mount-a-cifs-share-as-a-normal-user/) that suggests the following syntax

> //192.168.1.100/data /media/corpnet cifs username=johnny,domain=sealab,noauto,rw,users 0 0

When I change my entry to use this syntax like this:

```
\\192.x.x.x\web /mnt/web cifs username=X,password=X,domain=X,noauto,rw,users 0 0
```

and run `mount /mnt/web` I get

> mount.cifs: permission denied: no match for /mnt/web found in /etc/fstab

I then read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/493523/problem-with-cifs-util-mount-only-root-can-mount) along with it's highest voted answer, but the same error appears.

I have checked that my `web` folder in the `/mnt` directory has CHMOD 775, which should be ok.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE (see the discussion on the comments):**

You are typing \\ instead of //. For linux you must use // even if the network file system is running inside Windows.

**The old post:**

You are writing mount /mnt/web, but the directory you write in /etc/fstab was `/media/corpnet` so you need to write /mnt/web in /etc/fstab...

So change /media/corpnet

```
//192.168.1.100/data /media/corpnet cifs username=johnny,domain=sealab,noauto,rw,users 0 0
```

To /mnt/web:

```
//192.168.1.100/data /mnt/web cifs username=johnny,domain=sealab,noauto,rw,users 0 0
```

Or if you can't edit fstab change your command to mount /media/corpnet (**and you must create this directory too**)

Good lucky and if that works, please select this as the correct answer.

Comment: I am not using corpnet any place in my code. I was just quoting the syntax specified by the linked article. I'll edit my question to make this more obvious

Comment: Now you are typing \\ instead of // for linux you must use // even if the network file system is running inside Windows.

Comment: If you are not typing \\ and this is not the real file contents consider posting the real file.

Comment: That was it! Changing \\ to // fixed my problem!

Comment: I updated the answer with this information, please select it as the right answer.